# Open file - security warning when running a .bat file in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am having an issue finding/understanding how to solve the following issue when running a `.bat` file in `VBA` in `Excel`. I am getting an `Open File - Security Warning` prompt when I try and execute it.

The issue is i don't have administrative privileges, so I can't set `.bat` files as being ignored from this prompt, and this `.bat` file is one that I created myself so I don't understand why my computer is flagging it as potentially harmful.

If anyone could explain a workaround, and why such an issue arises despite it being a custom generated `.bat` file, I would greatly appreciate it. By a workaround I mean modifying the code I currently have to deal with this problem, without having to go through Administrators.

Below is the snippet of code pertaining to the problem, thanks:

```
sub test()
'some stuff

    Open MY_FILENAME For Output As #FileNumber
    Print #FileNumber, FileContents
    Print #FileNumber, "exit"
    Close #FileNumber

    'run batch file
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
    Dim rtn As Integer
    rtn = wsh.Run(Chr(34) & MY_FILENAME & Chr(34), windowStyle, waitOnReturn)
end sub
```

I should add that if run the shell like so I have no issues:

```
rtn = Shell(MY_FILENAME, vbNormalFocus)
```

Except that the code will continue running despite the shell not closing and completing its execution. I need the shell to halt until it has executed it's task.

Comment: Are you going to show us the batch file too? or are you satisfied that the batch file content does not in any way affect the reported issue? For instance, does the batch file current directory get set within itself? or are you expecting it to use whatever directory is current in the VBScript? BTW, if you're satisfied that the batch file content is irrelevant, can you please remove the batch-file tag, as batch file specialists do not need to see or be involved in your issue.

Comment: @Compo, apologies the batch file runs well. I just figured if the batch file was created by me maybe experts in that area would understand as to why it is being stated to be coming from an unknown source when I have created it within the vba code. I will remove the tag.